# Where in the FAR or AIM is a high speed taxi defined?

Tags: faa-regulations, taxiing, aim

While monitoring coms I recently heard a Cessna Centurion that had just cleared the runway request a "high speed taxi", which was approved by the tower. I'm assuming that means he wants to taxi at a faster than normal rate to his FBO of choice. Are high speed taxis defined somewhere as something you can request of ground control?

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/426/62)

Comment: Yeah @Pondlife I saw that - it is definitely related, but my specific question is whether or not there is something in the AIM or FAR that backs the radio coms I heard. I'd never heard another pilot request "high speed taxi" -- but it's not like i've logged 10,000 hours so that might just be my inexperience :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no definition in the AIM or regulations, as far as I know, but there is one in [the P/CG](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/), sort of (emphasis mine):

> HIGH SPEED TAXIWAY− A long radius taxiway designed and provided with
>   lighting or marking to define the path of aircraft, **traveling at high
>   speed (up to 60 knots)**, from the runway center to a point on the
>   center of a taxiway. Also referred to as long radius exit or turn-off
>   taxiway. The high speed taxiway is designed to expedite aircraft
>   turning off the runway after landing, thus reducing runway occupancy
>   time

So at least as far as the FAA is concerned, a high-speed taxi may be up to 60kts.

As for requesting it, you can request more or less anything. There's an active EAA chapter at my local airport and pilots who are in the process of building and testing aircraft sometimes request a high-speed taxi on the runway. The controllers don't question it or set any speed restrictions, it's all on the pilot. I suppose if things were busy they might deny the request, but the pilots know to do these things at quiet times anyway.

Comment: Remembering that for some aircraft taxying at 60kts is called 'taking off'.

Comment: A high speed taxiway (called rapid exit taxiway elsewhere) is specifically for vacating a runway. It doesn't seem to apply in this case.

Answer (score 6):

He was likely asking for approval to use the runway for a simulated take off without actually departing. Usually testing engine performance after modifications.

Comment: I think you're right. The parking he was heading towards is at the end of KTOA. He probably landed and was asking if it'd be ok to tie up the runway to get to the end of the airport faster.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Use case here is: after getting major repairs you want to test the plane in a series of tests. Short run up, long run up, taxi, high-speed taxi (enough to take off but dont), 1 lap around the pattern, couple laps, circle the airport for a while, then go out for a flight.

Answer (score 1):

The FAA does not provide a taxi speed limit but most airlines require observance of SOP "standard operating procedures" as part of their certification process. Normal SOP's are 30kts max with 10kts preferred. The rule I have seen for most flight training schools is *"no more than a fast walk"*.

While not specific to the FAA's FAR or AIM, this [FAA video](https://www.faa.gov/tv/?mediaId=1141) describes the design and requirements of high speed taxies and refers technical specifications to [AC 150-5300-13A-chg1](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150-5300-13A-chg1-interactive-201612.pdf). They define a high speed taxi as having ***no more than 30deg*** and nor more turn radius than ***1500ft***.

The exact dimension depends on aircraft category, IFR minimums, whether a reverse turn is needed, etc. No speed requirements are required, they define the accommodation for speed as ***"higher than normal taxi speed"***.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Taking a "High Speed Taxi" refers to using a specific taxiway designed to exit the runway at a high speed after landing. The term does NOT refer to using ANY taxiway at a high speed. Larger busier class D, C, and B airports have these highspeed taxiways.

An example of this is Taxiway Hotel at Van Nuys off of 16R. Thus the pilot you mentioned was requesting "the highspeed" taxiway to exit after landing. Whether he did that at a slow rate or fast rate was up to him. I frequently use the above taxiway at VNY because instead of taking the other taxiways at a 90 degree angle (which requires slowing down to almost a crawl to exit the runway), the highspeed is at a 30 degree angle to the runway which allows aircraft to exit the runway much faster than conventional taxiways. Busier airports want to get planes on and off the runway as fast as safely possible to help the flow of traffic. Highspeed taxiways help this process.

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE

Comment: Welcome to ASE, but wouldn't that airport feature be referred to as a "High Speed Taxiway", as noted in another answer, rather than a "High Speed Taxi"?